# Get TextView from another class for countdown

Tags: java, android, textview

I've created a class to make a countdown and used it to return the formated time as a TextView. However, I'm not beeing able to get the time to be exibed on in place. When, instead of calling the method getTime() I use a string, it shows fine.

The main method is like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

matchTime = findViewById(R.id.match_Time);

playTime = new Play();
matchTime.setText(playTime.getPlayTime());
```

While my class Play goes like this:

```
//Other implementations

    private void updatePlay() {
          int minutes = (int) (timeUntilEnd/ 1000) / 60;
          int seconds = (int) (timeUntilEnd/ 1000) % 60;

         timeUntilEndFormated= String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
         playTime.setText(timeUntilEndFormated);
    }

    public TextView getPlayTime() {
        return playTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are setting the text of matchTime to a TextView.
setText is a method that should receive a String, not a TextView object.

But, if you simply return a String in getPlayTime(), updatePlay() wont work because playTime.setText() wont affect matchTime at all.

To solve this you pass matchTime to Play's constructor, and then update it directly:

```
public class Play{
    
    private TextView matchTime;

    public Play(TextView matchTime){
        this.matchTime = matchTime;
    }

     private void updatePlay() {
       int minutes = (int) (timeUntilEnd/ 1000) / 60;
       int seconds = (int) (timeUntilEnd/ 1000) % 60;

       timeUntilEndFormated= String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
       matchTime.setText(timeUntilEndFormated);
     }
}
```

And then you only need to do this in your main method:

```
playTime = new Play(matchTime);
playTime.updatePlay();
```

Be careful with passing TextView's to other objects. This can create a memory leak, since TextView holds an instance of your Context. To avoid memory leaks you have to release the object in your activity's onDestroy() method:

```
 public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    playTime = null;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, man. It worked in the first try. I didnt get when I should call the onDestroy() method, tho. When I pause the timer or when I reset it? 
I'm wondering this, because I'm doind a basketball scoreboard. So When I pause it, I have to hold the time.

Comment: @EduardoBonatelli you shouldn't call onDestroy yourself. this is a method that you should override, that will be automatically called for you when your activity is destroyed. The reason you need it is to make sure that when your activity is destroyed, you dont leak any Context objects.

Comment: You can read about onDestroy and other lifecycle methods here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#:~:text=to%20App%20Architecture.-,Activity%2Dlifecycle%20concepts,activity%20enters%20a%20new%20state.

and read about Context memory leaks here:
 https://proandroiddev.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-memory-leaks-in-android-d7a59faaf46a

Comment: Thank you, very much. I've read the link you sent me and it was very insight full. I've just started with coding and it is all new to me. Bless you.